# QGIS geometry error:Hole lies outside shell

Tags: qgis, geometry, merge, error

I am using QGIS 3.8 and I am using a layer from OSM of Tokyo city.
The layer is consisted from many polygons and I have tried to merge it but I got error. 
This is how the original layer was look like:
[image]

This is the parts I manage to merge:
[image]

When I have checked the geometry validity no error appeard on the problematic areas, beside this one that appeard on area that I manage to merge. I have tried to check but couldn't find any visible error:

[image]

I really don't know how to fix it and how to merge the "green layers" with the pink ones. I have seen previous messages in this forum but they were using scripts.

any idea ?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Holes lies outside shell

Comment: Which tool are you using? Try to use Dissolve (Native and from GDAL) and Polygon dissolve from SAGA.

Comment: If you do not have a real topology error in your data you may suffer from an issue that is fixed lately. https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2019-October/050967.html. Unfortunately the fix is at the moment only in GDAL-master and you must either build GDAL yourself or download a ready made development version.

Comment: Can you share the file? This way it would be possible to see if there are other ways to solve the problem

Comment: The file is from the plugin "quickOSM", when you run query for the city tokyo (boundry, admisitrative)